# If I freeze pre-trained model weights and than train a classifier on top of its embeddings does that called fine-tunning?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, computer-vision

In the context of machine learning.  If I freeze pre-trained model weights (for example, BERT) and then train a classifier on top of its embeddings, does that called fine-tuning?

Answer (score 2):

**Wikipedia** defines "[fine-tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuning_(machine_learning))" as:

> an approach to transfer learning in which the weights of a pre-trained model are trained on new data. Fine-tuning can be done on the entire neural network, or on only a subset of its layers, in which case the layers that are not being fine-tuned are "frozen"

You didn't update any weights of the original model, so, at least according to Wikipedia, that wasn't "fine-tuning".

**On the other hand**, one can argue that nowadays the common use of "fine-tuning" covers much more than just *directly* updating the weights of the original model.

A popular [Parameter-Efficient Fine-Tuning](https://github.com/huggingface/peft) package by huggingface lists (soft)prompt tuning and Low-Rank Adaptation (LoRA) as its "fine-tuning" methods. It is possible to argue that these approaches do not *completely* satisfy the Wikipedia definition. Still, both approaches modify the original model weights, albeit indirectly: soft prompts modify the embedding vectors at the model inputs, and LoRA adds the low-rank restored matrices to the original model weights.

**Finally,** if somebody told me that he "fine-tuned BERT" and later I've discovered that he did what you've described -- I would think that I was misled. To me, the ultimate criterion than disqualifies something from being "fine-tuning" is the fact that for a fixed input you can just *save* the pre-trained BERT outputs and never return to running BERT inference again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would still be counted as a fine-tuning model. Unless untouching the pre-trained model, any modification that helps for your downstream task or to suit your data more IS an act of fine-tuning your model.